# Hibernate advanced mappings correct use @OneToOne

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have two Entities, Client and City. Client can be from one City only, and City can have many Clients from there. 
But I want for my City table to be independent, I want a relation from Client to City (City city in class Client), but I don't want any relation from my City class to Client.

Basically, a uni-directional mapping. How can I achieve that? @OneToOne? I'm using Spring and Hibernate.

Comment: [Google helps you](https://memorynotfound.com/hibernate-one-one-unidirectional-foreign-key/)

Answer (score -1):

```
class Client {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "city_id", nullable = false)
    City city;
}

class City {
}
```